# Spring Batch with modular=true and GenericApplicationContextFactory is cumbersome

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch with `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)`

The problem is that in this mode you have to explicitly declare which beans to initialize (i.e which classes Spring needs to scan)

Here's an exmaple:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)
public class ModularJobsConfig {
    @Autowired
    private AutomaticJobRegistrar registrar;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        registrar.addApplicationContextFactory(new GenericApplicationContextFactory(
                SomeJobConfig.class,
                SomeJobTasklet.class,
                SomeClassToDefineTaskExecutor.class
                SomeClassToRunTheJob.class));
    }
}
```

I can imagine that by the time I'll have several jobs, this configuration class will be bloated. How can I automate this?

It is worth mentioning that each job has its own package (e.g `com.example.jobs.<job_name>`) + they are defined in different maven-modules but I think it's irrelevant.

**Further Clarification**

I have a `core` module which contains the configuration above. Every job is defined in a separate maven module and it's been registered as a maven dependency in `core`.

Mainly for preventing naming clash, I'm using `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)` and I'm registering the jobs with `AutomaticJobRegistrar` as you can see in the example code above.

Ideally, I'd like Spring to scan the maven dependency and to do it for me (i.e. defining `GenericApplicationContextFactory`)

Currently, it's cumbersome to add manually each and every class (in the example above: `SomeJobConfig.class`, `SomeJobTasklet.class` etc)

As a counter example, if I didn't use `modular=true` I could let Spring Batch to load all beans on its own, but then I'd have to make sure methods names are unique across all the modules.

Comment: `The problem is that in this mode you have to explicitly declare which beans to initialize`: I don't understand this point, can you elaborate on why is that please? What's you issue if you don't declare which beans to initialize explicitly?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, Well, I'd rather that Spring itself will scan automatically, let's say, `com.example.jobs.<my_job>`. In the current state, for every class I'm adding I have to register it manually at the `GenericApplicationContextFactory` ctor'. I feel like it misses "the magic" of Spring

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (cause I've never used it), one method to facilitate the issue (of a bloated config class) is to use one `@Configuration` class per job which contains multiple `@Import` to a list of other `@Configuration` classes

Comment: Thanks, but the starting point `you have to explicitly declare which beans to initialize` is still not clear to me. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve (what is your specific problem) without referring to your attempted solution?

Comment: Separating jobs in different modules is a good idea, but why does the `core` module have a dependency to each job module? Why are you trying to register all jobs in the core module? `I'd like Spring to scan the maven dependency and to do it for me`: I see no way to do that. To be honest, if it were up to me and things start to get more complicated than they should be, I would keep it simple and give each job a different name.. BTW, I have never had to use `modular=true`, I package each job in its own module and run each job separately from the CLI.

Comment: So the idea is that each job has its own module. Mainly for the purpose of a separation of concerns but at the same time, you have one module to control the jobs (core). For example, I'd like to have `@Autowired Map<String, Job> jobs` and to be able to spawn a job by its name (e.g. from a REST request).  

At the end of the day, if it's infeasible I'd compromise with having one module with some appropriate hierarchy in order to keep things organized but simple.

Comment: By the way, `I would keep it simple and give each job a different name` - It's not only the jobs names but also the beans names (e.g. reader(), processor() etc). But yeah, I can apply some convention. It shouldn't be a big deal, even though it's not enforced on the developer, it can be tracked easily at runtime.